# Generating Function of Riordan numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I would like to find generating function of $f(n)$, where $f(n)$ is defined as following:
$$f(n)=\sum_k^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}C_k\text{.}$$
With $C_k=\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}$($C_k$ is the $k^{th}$ Catalan's number).

Comment: What have you tried? Why don't start by writing the definition of the generating function and exchange the two sums?

Comment: According to https://oeis.org/A005043, the generating function is
$$
\frac{1 + x - \sqrt{1-2x-3x^2}}{2x(1+x)}
$$
but I imagine you are actually looking for a proof, not just the answer, and I do not have one.

Answer (score 5):

We have for the sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^{n-k} C_k
= \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k C_{n-k}
\\ = [z^n] \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k z^k
= [z^n] \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}
(1-z)^n
\\ = \; \underset{z}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1-z)^n
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}.$$

Now put $z/(1-z) = w$ so that $z=w/(1+w)$ and $dz = 1/(1+w)^2 \; dw$
to find

$$\; \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w)
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4w/(1+w)}}{2w/(1+w)}
\frac{1}{(1+w)^2}
\\ = \; \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1+w-\sqrt{(1+w)^2-4w(1+w)}}{2w(1+w)}
\\ = \; \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1+w-\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2}}{2w(1+w)}.$$

It follows that the desired OGF is

$$\frac{1+w-\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2}}{2w(1+w)}.$$

Comment: How did you trasform $\sum_k^n\binom{n}{k}\cdots $ into $[z^n]\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\cdots$. Sorry, but during my course of discrete maths we did really few about generating function. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Maybe, i got this, you observed that generating function of $C_{n-k}$ is $x^k \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$

Comment: What does $\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} $ mean? Because I have fully understood that you see the Riordan's generating function as a product between the Catalan's generating function and $(1-z)^n$, but after that, how did you manage to get rid of that $n$?

Comment: This is the residue operator from Egorychev's *Combinatorial sums.*

Comment: @MarkoRiedel thank you. Do you know whether we can follow another way that leads to the same result, starting from $[z^n](1-z)^n
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$? Because I have the same exercise in my notes, but we haven't done the residue operator.

Comment: Yes. Start from $\sum_{n\ge 0} w^n \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^{n-k} C_k$ and interchange summations.